# HTML5 Drag, prevent a dragged image from redirecting when dropped

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I'm using the jQuery file uploader here: http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

The problem is. I have the file uploader running in Browser Window 1. If I then open Browser Window 2 and drag an image from window 2 into Window 1, window 1 redirects to the image.

How can I prevent Window 1 from redirecting when Browser Window 2 drags an image into it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can prevent image from draging by this:

```
$('img').on('dragstart', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

or try prevent default behavior on drop:

```
$("html").on("dragover", function(e) { e.preventDefault();  e.stopPropagation(); });
$("html").on("drop", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation(); });
```

Comment: It redirects before drop is ever reached. preventDefault isn't working on dragstart

Comment: try to add `dragover` and `e.stopPropagation();`. I just tested in chrome, for me it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

add the callbacks to your drop target like this:

```js
$('#a').on('dragover', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
$('#a').on('drop', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

It works for me on Chrome.